# How do I select wireframes objects and edit them?

Tags: wireframe

I have accidentally joined an object with a group of objects but this made me unable to select the group of objects individually. To fix this, I separated the combined object by loose parts, and I can now select the individual objects again in wireframe mode.

However, after trying to edit the selected objects (i.e. click on Edit Mode), all objects are  deselected. I am unable to select individual objects unless I’m in wireframe mode. Is there a way for me to select these objects and edit them?

Comment: share your file using this link https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can help you

Comment: "I am unable to select individual objects unless I’m in wireframe mode", this is weird, but do you know that you can select several objects in Object mode then switch to Edit mode and you'll be able to edit them all, if this is your question?